# Distribution of maximum over minimum of Weibull(alpha, 1)

Tags: probability, order-statistics, weibull-distribution

Let the PDF of Weibull $(\alpha, 1)$ be

$$
f_X (x) = \alpha x^{\alpha-1} \exp\left( - x^{\alpha}\right) 
$$

I know from **probability integral transfrom** that

$$
X_{(1)}^{\alpha} \overset{d}{=} Z_{(1)} \\
\cdots \\
X_{(n)}^{\alpha} \overset{d}{=} Z_{(n)}
$$

where $X_{(n)}$ denotes $n^{th}$ order statistic from Weibull samples, and $Z_{(n)}$ denotes $n^{th}$ order statistic from samples of $\operatorname{Exp}(1)$.

Can anybody derive the PDF of $X_{(n)}/X_{(1)}$, without using the **change-of-variables** technique, with which I keep failing?

Comment: Your formula for $f(x)$ is incorrect; the last term should be $\exp\{-x^{\alpha}\}$.  Would that fix the problems with your derivation for you?

Comment: @jbowman oh thanks, I simply mistyped the PDF. Still failing to solve it.

Comment: Maybe this post would be of help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/306294/119261.

Comment: Using change of variables, I am faced with the integral $\int_0^\infty s^{2\alpha-1}(e^{-s^\alpha}-e^{-r^\alpha s^\alpha})^{n-2}e^{-s^\alpha(1+r^\alpha)}\,ds$ where $r>1, \alpha>0$ to get the marginal pdf of $R=X_{(n)}/X_{(1)}$. Plugging the integral directly into *Mathematica* (additionally setting $n\ge 2$) gives a rather ugly answer in terms of non-elementary functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am proceeding with the *change of variables* technique because it  is straightforward. The only catch is the integral to find the required distribution as a marginal density, but that can be taken care of. If this is what you tried to do on your first attempt, I think you can finish the derivation now if you stick with it.

*Restating known facts:*

The population density is

$$f(x)=\alpha x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x^{\alpha}}\mathbf1_{x>0}\,,\quad\alpha>0$$

Corresponding distribution function is $$F(x)=1-e^{-x^{\alpha}}\mathbf1_{x>0}$$

Joint pdf of $(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})=(U,V)$ is

$$f_{U,V}(u,v)=n(n-1)\alpha^2\left(e^{-u^\alpha}-e^{-v^\alpha}\right)^{n-2}(uv)^{\alpha-1}e^{-u^{\alpha}-v^{\alpha}}\mathbf1_{0<u<v}$$

Changing variables $(U,V)\to(R,S)$ such that $R=V/U$ and $S=U$.

So joint density of $(R,S)$ is

$$f_{R,S}(r,s)=n(n-1)\alpha^2r^{\alpha-1}s^{2\alpha-1}\left(e^{-s^\alpha}-e^{-r^\alpha s^\alpha}\right)^{n-2}e^{-s^{\alpha}(1+r^{\alpha})}\mathbf1_{r>1,s>0}$$

At this point, I took some help from our [maths site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2855731/evaluating-int-0-infty-x2-alpha-1e-x-alpha-e-r-alpha-x-alphan) to simplify the ensuing integral in terms of elementary functions. Now that I see it, the simplification is obvious.

For $r>1$, marginal density of $R$ is

\begin{align}
f_{R}(r)&=n(n-1)\alpha^2r^{\alpha-1}\int_0^\infty s^{2\alpha-1}\left(e^{-s^\alpha}-e^{-r^\alpha s^\alpha}\right)^{n-2}e^{-s^{\alpha}(1+r^{\alpha})}\,ds
\\&=n(n-1)\alpha r^{\alpha-1}\int_0^\infty y\left(e^{-y}-e^{-r^\alpha y}\right)^{n-2}e^{-(1+r^\alpha)y}\,dy\qquad[\,s\mapsto s^\alpha=y\,]
\\&=n(n-1)\alpha r^{\alpha-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-2}\binom{n-2}{j}(-1)^j\int_0^\infty ye^{-(r^\alpha (1+j)+n-j-1)y}\,dy
\end{align}

That last step was just expanding the integrand using the binomial theorem.

Simplifying further we have the required density:

$$f_R(r)=n(n-1)\alpha r^{\alpha-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-2}\binom{n-2}{j}\frac{(-1)^j}{\left(n+(r^\alpha -1)(1+j)\right)^2}\mathbf1_{r>1}$$

I think this is about the best we can do without going into special functions. This is also pretty much the same as done in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/306311/119261) answer to a similar question.

Maybe someone could give a verification of the above pdf.